# Facebook login is not working In-app browser for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, iframe

I'm using following script for login using Facebook JavaScript API.

```
var permissions = [
    'email',
    'user_friends'
].join(',');

FB.login(function (response) {
    // if login was successful, execute the following code
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //Perform next set of methods
    }
}, {scope: permissions});
```

This is working in all browsers and in Android (this script is rendering inside an iframe).

But when a user open the login page in Facebook In-app browser for iOS, then the login is not working. Popup is not showing.

After spending some time to fix this, the issue is happening only when I include the login page in an iframe.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Can you add some logs or debugging info (like server response, etc.)

Comment: Hey @David'mArm'Ansermot
Since I'm trying this from iOS Facebook in-app browser. Couldn't find any logs. But when I tried to alert the response it returns nothing and not even getting into the async function.

Comment: You can activate the developer console for safari in you iPhone settings

Comment: But the url is opening in Facebook in-app browser. Does it help if I enable console in safari? Thanks.

Comment: To know it, just enable and see if you have logs... Try it by yourself...

Comment: Enable the log and not working :(

Comment: But what's written in the console ? Put it in your question

Comment: Couldn't console any data. Console works for Safari and not working for Facebook in-app browser.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue. You need to use `FB.getLoginStatus` then if the user is not logged in, use `FB.login`. Just make sure to call `FB.login` after user click or else you will get a popup blocked.